# Clob Conversion in Callable Statement with Connection Object

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a paragraph with more than 4000 characters i.e. size is more than 4 kb of text.

1. How to convert it into Clob with Connection object?
2. Is it possible to cast `oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection` object as `java.sql.Connection` Object so that i can use Clob Conversion as follows:

   ```
   CLOB clob = new CLOB(OracleConnection orcl,Byte[] byt)
   ```

and then set it in statement as

```
stmt=con.prepareCall("{call xyz(?)}");
stmt.setClob(1, clob);
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: An `OracleConnection` already is a `java.sql.Connection`, there is no need to cast it. What is keeping you from doing this now?

Comment: Actually second was question out of curiosity...i needed answer of first question. @MarkRotteveel

Comment: This is a good example why you should restrict a question to a single question ;) I read it as a sequence of steps, not two questions. But then the question remains, what exactly doesn't work with your current code?